# IOS Push many view controller without pop

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller

I wanted to know what will happen if we keep pushing same view controllers again n again. I have 4 buttons, each of which triggers a View. All the 4 buttons are there in all the 4 views.So each time I click a button a view is loaded. So I am pushing a view controller. will this lead some kind of memory management issue or nay other issue? Any other way to handle this? I cant use Tab bar cause of design issues.

I WANT TO BASICALLY IMPLEMENT A TAB BAR WITH 4 BUTTONS. I CANT USE A TAB BAR DUE TO DESIGN ISSUES

Answer (score 1):

This won't lead to any specific memory management issue. Every time you allocate an object it takes up some memory. When you push the view controller you are just allocating a new copy of that object. Whether it's a view controller or a data model or a string, each object takes up some memory. You can easily profile how much additional memory gets used each time you push the view controller, but most likely it is negligible (probably much less than 1kb depending on how much you have in there). I just profiled one of my view controllers and it used 320 bytes. So for simple math, let's say each push takes up 1kb of memory. And an iPhone 5 has 1Gb of RAM. That's enough to hold about 1 million view controllers. So I wouldn't worry about it.

However, if you want to worry about it then you should implement `didReceiveMemoryWarning` in your view controller and release any unneeded objects.

Comment: @Luca, you should probably comment rather than edit my answer. Considering that as of July 2014 99% of iPhones are running iOS6+ I don't think we need to provide answers for iOS5 development.

Comment: Probably you are right about the edit. i thought that was better to specify it there with a small edit rather than create confusion with another answer or comments.
There are still companies that are supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add back btn from your 4 other controllers. On back its removed from navigation stack memory is reclaimed .

If you still have to manual way of managing it, you can use `[self.navigationController viewControllers]` to check if viewController is there or not and take appropriate decision.

Comment: The nav controller automatically provides a back button. He doesn't need to add it.

Comment: I don't understand what means the second sentence. What you should check in the viewControllers? They will be not deallocate until that they are removed from the navigation stack.

Comment: @turbo thanks for answer. I will rephrase my question in one line. I want to implement a tab bar with 4 buttons as I cant use tab bar due to design issues